# Why CSS text-align property centers block-level content?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I’ve got 2 questions.
1) Is the text inside the navigation links centered because I set the value of the display property of those links(a tags) to `block` and now it’s basically the same thing as if I was centering text inside a `p` element?
2) I set the display property of `i` elements(font awesome icons) to `block` too, so why are these elements centered as well? If you change the display property on the `i` elements to `table`, then these icons are not being centered. Shouldn’t `block` value behave the same as `table` in this case? As far as I know I can only use `text-align` to align inline and inline-block elements. So why is this working?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Text-align</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <style>
            .cf:before,
            .cf:after {
                content: "";
                display: block;
            }
            
            .cf:after {
                clear: both;
            }
            
            body {
                margin: 0;
                font: 16px/1 sans-serif;
            }
            
            nav {
                height: 120px;
                background-color: #f2f2f2;
                padding: 0 5%;
            }
            
            ul {
                list-style: none;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
            
            li {
                float: left;
                color: #a6a6a6;
                border-left: 1px solid #a6a6a6;
            }
            
            li:last-child {
                border-right: 1px solid #a6a6a6;
            }
            
            li:hover {
                color: #de5728;
            }
            
            a {
                display: block;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: inherit;
                font-size: 10px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                padding: 37px 0;
                width: 136px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            
            nav a .fa {
                display: block;
                font-size: 36px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul class="cf">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-shield"></i> Domov
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i> Portfolio
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i> O nas
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> Kontakt
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. Block *containers* can have text-align applied, which aligns their *content*.
2. Block-level elements in normal flow take up the full width of their containing block, which in your example is the width of the content box of the li elements.

The content box width of the element is calculated according to this equality:

> 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 
>      'width' + 
>      'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = 
>      width of containing block

In your example, the margins and paddings resolve to 0, and the borders to 0 or 1 pixels. The containing block is provided by the `<a>` element and the remainder of its width is the content box width of the `<i>` element when it is `display:block`.

The text-align property is inherited, so the `<i>` element takes on the alignment and centres its content within the width of its content box, the content for the `<i>` element being provided by fontawesome via the `:before` pseudo-element.

Table elements are block-level, but they resolve the equality differently. Instead, the width of their content box is shrink-to-fit, and any remaining width of the containing block is, in your example, given to the right margin instead.

This puts the table over to the left side of its container, and the content (again the generated content from fontawesome) goes tightly inside that. The anonymous table cell created inside the table still inherits the text-align setting, but there's no space either side of the content for it to move in. So it too appears to be on the left side of the floated `<li>` element whose width is determined by tightly wrapping the `<a>` element inside it.

Comment: Thank you, perfect answer! I missed the fact the actual icons are generated using `:before`, so this is why `text-align` affects them. Thanks for pointing out the difference between `block` and `table` too.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes. block level (and inline-block with a width) can have text-align:center applied.
2. the i elements will inherit from their parent, the a tag, and so will also be centered.

Display block and table are very different to each other in that the child elements are rendered differently, i.e children of a table would likely be display:table-cell.

Also, text-align really makes no sense on inline elements.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. Hm, but those `i` tags have no content, they are empty. So, even though they inherit the `text-align` property there is no content to apply it to. I don't understand this part.

Comment: Should I perceive those icons as content generated between those `i` tags? Since there is actually nothing inside those tags I kind of perceived those icons a `background-image` of the `i` element. Could you please elaborate on this a bit more?

Comment: The icons use pseudo elements (:before, :after etc( to generate the actual icons.  / stopped reply as I notice its been explained above